# Android App not starting up

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile

I am using Android Studio and developing simple application.After some changes I am getting below error -

Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/bind/Binder.class":
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:going on.
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex '/Users/Vaibhav/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.2.7/2f51c4bb4724ea408096ee9100ff2827e07e5b7c/jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar' to '/Users/Vaibhav/AndroidStudioProjects/KinjalCreation/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/debug/folders/1000/10/jaxb-api-2.2.7_811145ebcd68e42de83f25d0fbd06ba531e55bd4'

I am not sure what is the cause?

Build.gradle for app -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "kinjalcreation.com.kinjalcreation"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
            exclude 'META-INF/plexus/components.xml'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
        compile group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'ipp-v3-java-devkit', version: '2.9.0'

        compile group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-core', version: '1.2.1.2'

        compile group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-commonshttp4', version: '1.2.1.2'

        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.3.1'
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.1'
        compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'


    }
```

Comment: why are you using two versions of http core ?

Comment: Sorry , removed that .

Comment: try with different  sdk version. May be a bug in 26

Comment: Tried with that but still its not working

Comment: also try removing useLibrary line

Comment: I am using http-core jar so I need to use otherwise it give compilation error as it will try to use android http-core

Comment: I want to say for testing purpose try it once

Comment: Application giving compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Javax.xml.bind was used with multiple dependency.

After adding following code , it started working.

```
compile (group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'ipp-v3-java-devkit', version: '2.9.0'){
    exclude group: "javax.xml.bind", module: "jaxb-api"
    exclude group: "javax.xml.bind", module: "jsr173_api"
}
```